# EE3 - When image description is blank, use title field

Tags: conditionals, file-manager, files

I'm running into a roadblock here. Basically my client wants to use the "description" field of a file as the alt text, unless it isn't filled out, then he wants it to fall back to the page title. I am using this:

```
<li class="large-4 small-3 columns">
     {if right_image_1:description }
        {right_image_1}<img class="avatar w-alt" alt="{description}" src="{url}" />{/right_image_1}
    {if:else}
        <img class="avatar wo-alt" alt="{title}" src="{right_image_1}" />
    {/if}
</li>
```

But it keeps defaulting to the title field no matter what info i have in the description. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try testing against a known value? `{if right_image_1:description != ""}`

Comment: ↑↑↑ What he said ↑↑↑

Comment: @jrothafer did that, no change.

Comment: @jcogs.eecms no change when I do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li class="large-4 small-3 columns">
    {right_image_1}
    {if description}
        <img class="avatar w-alt" alt="{description}" src="{url}" />
    {if:else}
        <img class="avatar wo-alt" alt="{title}" src="{url}" />
    {/if}
    {/right_image_1}
</li>
```

Comment: Drats, I should have thought of that, of course it's variable pair. GJ Kevin Carpenter